# Search Elements from Xml matching with a list of ids

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, list

Hi I have a xml containing book details. Structure of xml is -

```
<Root>
    <Books>
        <Book>
            <BookId>1</BookId>
            <Title>Book 1</Title>
            <LanguageId>1</LanguageId>
            <Genres>2,3</Genres>
            <BookType>1</BookType>
            <Description>Lorem Ipsum</Description>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <BookId>3</BookId>
            <Title>Book 3</Title>
            <LanguageId>3</LanguageId>
            <Genres>12,23</Genres>
            <BookType>2</BookType>
            <Description>Lorem Ipsum</Description>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <BookId>3</BookId>
            <Title>Book 2</Title>
            <LanguageId>2</LanguageId>
            <Genres>1,13</Genres>
            <BookType>2</BookType>
            <Description>Lorem Ipsum</Description>
        </Book>
         <Book>
            <BookId>4</BookId>
            <Title>Book 4</Title>
            <LanguageId>2</LanguageId>
            <Genres>1,13</Genres>
            <BookType>2</BookType>
            <Description>Lorem Ipsum</Description>
        </Book>
    </Books>
</Root>
```

One Book can have multiple genre ids and can have multiple languages.
I have a list of genre ids,list of languages and list of booktypes.

I want to fetch all the books whose genre id, language id and booktype matches that list.

I used LINQ query for this as it will be more efficient that looping through all the book xml nodes-

```
  List<XElement> elems = xldoc.Root.Descendants("Books")
                                     .Descendants("Book")
                                     .Where(x=> 
                                   (listofgenres.Contains(x.Element("GenreId").Value)) &&  
                                   (listoflanguages.Contains(x.Element("LanguageId").Value)) &&
                                   (listofbooktypes.Contains(x.Element("BookType").Value)))
                                    .ToList();
```

But it didn't fetch results as I wanted. What am I doing wrong???

If suppose I have a list of bookIds like 1,3,4,2 and I want to fetch book with these ids in same order as my list what is the other way around by linq. Now I am fetching books by ids one by one by looping through all the xml nodes and adding to a collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;



namespace ConsoleApplication43
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> order = new List<int>() { 1, 3, 4, 2 };
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            List<XElement> books = doc.Descendants("Book").OrderBy(x => order.IndexOf((int)x.Element("BookId"))).ToList();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I used your logic but it returned all the book nodes `List<int> order = new List<int>() { 1, 3,  };List<XElement> books = xldoc.Root.Element("Books").Descendants("Book").OrderBy(x => bookids.IndexOf((int)x.Element("BookId"))).ToList();`

Comment: You then need to add : Where(x => order.Contains((int)x.Element("BookId"))

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any `GenreId` in your xml. You have `Genres`, that is comma separated list of genres.
I think you wanted to do something like:

```
List<XElement> elems = xldoc.Root.Descendants("Books")
        .Descendants("Book")
        .Where(x=> (listofgenres.Intersect(x.Element("Genres").Value.Split(',')).Any())
                   && (listoflanguages.Contains(x.Element("LanguageId").Value)) 
                   && (listofbooktypes.Contains(x.Element("BookType").Value)))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Yeah Genres are genre ids with comma separated.

Comment: @ThirueswaranRajagopalan  thank you. I had the sam in LInqPad, the question is, waht is expected, i have assumed, that intersection is expected, could be,  that all genres should be in listofgenres.

Comment: if I have a list of ids and I want to get them elements from xml using linq in order same as my list then what changes I have to make. Usually I loop through all my nodes of xml and fetch element by id one by one and then add it to a collection.

Comment: @Maksim Simkin I have a list of ids and the node from which I have to compare is comma separated ids, I am having difficulty in retrieving it

Comment: @Sonali could you create another question fo it? For this one you have already an accepted answer.